# Parsing XML with Fortran using xmlf90

Tags: xml, fortran

I need to parse XML files with a Fortran program.  I'm evaluating the [xmlf90 parser tool](http://fisica.ehu.es/ag/xml/) to see if it will be useful for my needs, but I'm having trouble getting the example problem in the user's manual to work.  The error has to do with a type mismatch:

```
                 pcdata_chunk_handler=pcdata_chunk )
                                      1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'pcdata_chunk_handler' at (1); 
passed REAL(4) to UNKNOWN
```

I copied the example directly from the user's manual.  This is my main program, which calls the xml parser:

```
program inventory
use flib_sax
use m_handlers

type(xml_t) :: fxml     ! XML file object (opaque)
integer :: iostat

call open_xmlfile("inventory.xml",fxml,iostat)
if (iostat /= 0) stop "cannot open xml file"

call xml_parse(fxml, begin_element_handler=begin_element, &
                 end_element_handler=end_element,     &   
                 pcdata_chunk_handler=pcdata_chunk )

end program inventory
```

This is the "m_handlers" module:

```
module m_handlers
use flib_sax
private
!
public :: begin_element, end_element, pcdata_chunk
!
logical, private :: in_item, in_description, in_price
character(len=40), private :: what, price, currency, id
!
contains !-----------------------------------------
!
    subroutine begin_element(name,attributes)
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: name
        type(dictionary_t), intent(in) :: attributes

        integer :: status

        select case(name)
        case("item")
            in_item = .true.
            call get_value(attributes,"id",id,status)
        case("description")
            in_description = .true.
        case("price")
            in_price = .true.
            call get_value(attributes,"currency",currency,status)
        end select
    end subroutine begin_element
    !----------------------------------------------------------------
    subroutine pcdata_chunk_handler(chunk)
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: chunk

        if (in_description) what = chunk
        if (in_price) price = chunk

    end subroutine pcdata_chunk_handler
    !----------------------------------------------------------------
    subroutine end_element(name)
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: name

        select case(name)
        case("item")
            in_item = .false.
            write(unit=*,fmt="(5(a,1x))") trim(id), trim(what), ":", &
                trim(price), trim(currency)

        case("description")
            in_description = .true.
        case("price")
            in_price = .false.

        end select

    end subroutine end_element
    !----------------------------------------------------------------
end module m_handlers
```

The "inventory.xml" file that I parse is:

```
<inventory>
<item id="003">
    <description>Washing machine</description>
    <price currency="euro">1500.00</price>
</item>
<item id="007">
    <description>Microwave oven</description>
    <price currency="euro">300.00</price>
</item>
<item id="011">
    <description>Dishwasher</description>
    <price currency="swedish crown">10000.00</price>
</item>
</inventory>
```

If I get rid of the "pcdata_chunk_handler=pcdata_chunk" argument from the "call xml_parse" statement, this program works, but of course, the description and price data is missing from the output.

Answer (score 2):

In the user's manual for xmlf90, there is an error in the m_handlers module.  The subroutine "pcdata_chunk_handler" should actually be named "pcdata_chunk", since that is what it is called in the argument of the "call xml_parse" statement found in the main program, as well as what it is called at the top of the module file "public :: begin_element, end_element, pcdata_chunk".